# Typescript: omit undefined/null properties from type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I was trying to create new type from a type, but remove any property that it's value is undefined|null, this to create a fetch function that require/not require a payload argument.

The main type is:

```
type TEndpointsPayload = {
    getList: undefined,
    open: {
        id: string
    }
    close: {
        id: string
    }
}
```

while I'm trying to create a new type that will look like so:

```
type TEndpointsNonEmptyPayload = {
    open: {
        id: string
    }
    close: {
        id: string
    }
}
```

So the `getList` is omitted because it's value is undefined/not an object.

I've tried many methods, include `Omit`, `Exclude` and so, but non seem to actully remove the property from the type, but instead set him as `never`..

Any help would be muhch appreciated!

The function looks something like so (assuming the `TEndpointsNonEmptyPayload` actually works):

`private reuqest<T extends keyof TEndpointsNonEmptyPayload>(endpoint: T, payload: TEndpointsNonEmptyPayload[T]): void;`

and to solve this I was thinking of creating some function overload looking like so:

`private reuqest<T extends keyof TEndpointsPayload>(endpoint: T): void;`

Would happy to hear some ideas on the type or the function implementation!

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBJbdN) what you're looking for?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Not sure why you're also asking about the function implementation, it seems like a separate/followup question and SO posts should be focused on a single question.  Do you want to either remove that part or [edit] the question to clarify?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of `OmitNullish<T>` below excludes keys from being added to the mapped type at all if they have a value of type `null|undefined`, rather than setting their values to `never`. Does it do what you want?

Edit: It looks like me and Jcalz have arrived at not only the same answer, but even the same alias `OmitNullish<T>` (as per linked comment above). Great minds think alike!

```js
type TEndpointsPayload = {
  getList: undefined;
  open: {
    id: string;
  };
  close: {
    id: string;
  };
};

type OmitNullish<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends null | undefined ? never : K]: T[K];
};

type TEndpointsNonEmptyPayload = OmitNullish<TEndpointsPayload>;
```

Comment: Hi, Jcalz. I didn't read your answer yet at all.

Comment: Okay, then it's just great minds thinking alike. Removing comments

Comment: Wow yes I can see why you thought so

Comment: Thank you very much cefn! It was indeed what I was looking for, wans't familiar with the 'as' approach on the keys iteration. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to remove optional and undefined properties from a type you can define `OmitNullish` type using `NonNullable` this way:

```
type OmitNullish<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends NonNullable<T[K]> ? K : never]: T[K];
};
```

This can be used this way:

```
type MyType = {
    one?: string,
    two: number,
    three: undefined,
}

type WithoutNulls = OmitNullish<MyType>
```

The new type `WithoutNulls` will be:

```
type WithoutNulls = {
    two: number;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQVtQPYDsIB%20ALigGdgAnAS3wHMAaLHYAd1zPwFcBbAIwhVmOKMAAWVCBDLd8AEwgAzOhHnMAvhgyhIUAPK8awAHLcANuZrlxAHngA%20KKkzYA2gGkodKAGsIILhKUPBQAIbkIZ4AulAQAB7AEAqRJgRmlmH85hD2MU5EUF5cEABuQtFk8DEA3BgadTpIUADqxuK43KYW5pGohsYZVja2cIiQDtoA9FOt0ADGYfhQ81JhSWLi0LhguOTG0LqHuFD0EMB4%20OYgUDyZ2dBgVDtCwDQQkRLWUGxhIE16fRXEBDax2RzOdAsTzeZb%20QLBUIRKIeWIJJIpKBpfBDLI5PKogq3MpCKBkVFVWr1RpHVrtIZ9AzA0EjMZIBxAA)

Comment: Thank you Fernando! I was accepting the other answer as it was first, and I didn't wish to remove optional params. But indeed this was an acceptable answer as-well, much appreciated, Thank you!