# Failed to implement Typescript function overload

Tags: typescript, overloading, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

Following the last question:
[Typescript: omit undefined/null properties from type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75616258/typescript-omit-undefined-null-properties-from-type/75630476#75630476)

Using TS, I was trying to implmenet an overload for a function named `request` which can accept `payload` or not, by the `TEndpointsPayload`(code below) (When property contain null, there is no need to pass payload),

Giving the following types:

```
export type TEndpointsPayload = {
    getList: null, //No payload required
    open: {
        name: string
    }
    close: {
        name: string
    }
}

export type TEndpointsWithPayload = {
    [K in keyof TEndpointsPayload as TEndpointsPayload[K] extends null ? never : K]: TEndpointsPayload[K]; //Contains the 'open' | 'close'
}; //Will create a type: {'open': {name: string}, 'close': {name: string}}

export type TEndpointsWithoutPayload = {
    [K in keyof TEndpointsPayload as TEndpointsPayload[K] extends null ? K : never]: TEndpointsPayload[K]; //Contains only the 'getList'
}; //Will create a type: {'getList': null}
```

This is the function overload implementation

```
//This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.ts(2394)
  private async request<T extends keyof TEndpointsWithoutPayload>(endpointName: T): Promise<TEndpointsResponse[T]>;

//Code never fall into this implementation
  private async request<T extends keyof TEndpointsWithPayload>(endpointName: T, payload: TEndpointsWithPayload[T]): Promise<TEndpointsResponse[T]> { ... }
```

Currently I'm having 2 issues, one is where the first `request` function having error

`This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.ts(2394)`

Which is solved when adding `?` to the `payload` argument (but not what I'm intended to do as payload should not be optional, but required/not exist depends on the `TEndpointsPayload`)

and second, is where any usage of those methods, fall to the first `request` implemenmtation (aka: only allow to pass `request('getList')` without a payload).

I didn't manage to have the following behavior:

```
request('getList')//OK
request('open', {name}) //OK
request('getList', {test}) //ERROR, no payload allow
request('open') // ERROR, payload required
```

Thank you! Any hint or help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorty after posting this question, I've come into the solution.
Apparently there is need to declare both the function scenarios and the implement a third one which handle all of those.
So the correct function overload will look like this:

```
    private async request<T extends keyof TEndpointsWithoutPayload>(endpointName: T): Promise<TEndpointsResponse[T]>;
    private async request<T extends keyof TEndpointsWithPayload>(endpointName: T, payload: TEndpointsWithPayload[T]): Promise<TEndpointsResponse[T]>;
    private async request<T extends keyof TEndpointsPayload>(endpointName: T, payload?: TEndpointsPayload[T]): Promise<TEndpointsResponse[T]> {
//handle both scenarios
}
```

Hope it helps to anyone come across the same question!